# Scraping from beautifulsoup in Python with a for loop just returns the last result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage using beautifulsoup and (ultimately) output it into a csv. As a first step in this, I've tried to get the text of the relevant table. I managed to do this, but the code no longer gives me the same output when I rerun it: instead of returning all 12372 records when I run the for loop, it just saves the last one.

An abbreviated version of my code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
BirthsSoup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="html.parser")
print(BirthsSoup.prettify()) 
# this confirms that the soup has captured the page as I want it to

birthsTable = BirthsSoup.select('#t2 td')
# selects all the elements in the table I want

birthsLen = len(birthsTable)
# birthsLen: 12372

for i in range(birthsLen):
    print(birthsTable[i].prettify())
# this confirms that the beautifulsoup tag object correctly captured all of the table

for i in range(birthsLen):
    birthsText = birthsTable[i].getText()
# this was supposed to compile the text for every element in the table
```

But the for loop only saves the text for the last (ie 12372nd) element in the table. Do I need to do something else in order for it to save each element when it loops through? I think my previous (desired) output had the text of each element on a new line.

This is my first time using python, so apologies if I've made an obvious mistake.

Comment: How do you do `for i in range(birthsLen):` and then define `birthsLen` after that?

Comment: I must have copied the lines of code across in the wrong order, I've edited it now to correct it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're doing is overwriting your birthText string each iteration, so by the time it gets to the end only the last one will be saved. To solve this, create a list and append each line:

```
birthsLen = len(birthsTable)
birthsText = []

for i in range(birthsLen):
    birthsText.append(birthsTable[i].getText())
```

Or, more concisely:

```
birthsText = [line.getText() for line in birthsTable]
```

Comment: or even birthsText = [line.text for line in  BirthsSoup.select('#t2 td')]